# I been suffering a problem when I run php artisan migrate command

Tags: laravel

When I run php artisan migrate command then I see this error. I have an idea for this error is that I deleted the product migration from the migrations table. What can I do to migrate the product table?

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'products' already exists (SQL: create table `products`(`id`bigint unsigned not null auto_increm ent primary key, `category_id` int not null, `subcategory_id` int not null, `product_name` ...) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
> at F:\xampp\htdocs\suzayetstore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Datahase\Connection.php:742

> F:\xampp\htdocs\suzayetstore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:527 PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42501]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'products' already exists")

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. The products table already exists, so it cannot run the migration. You have to delete the products table and run the migration again.
This is not good practice. If you want to undo a migration, please run `php artisan migrate:rollback` This will undo the last batch of migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens because you already have a table in your database and you are trying to migrate the same table without droping(deleting) it. You have 2 options which I have explained below,

If you already dont have any datas in your database tables. Then you can use,

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

So that all the tables will be deleted and recreated again.

If you need already have datas in any of your table in your database. And you need the datas. You just need to delete the table from database. For that use the query below,

```
drop table tablename;
```

And then, run the below command,

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: It's not refresh... it's `php artisan migrate:fresh`. `php artisan migrate:refresh` is a two in one command that executes the :rollback command and the migrate command.

Comment: Got it. I have updated it.Thanks you for the info.

Comment: @Refilon you know you can improve answers by editing them. no need for a downvote because of a typo. His answer is on point and exactly what should be done, plus the condition for each case.

Comment: @N69S It's not a type. Refresh is also a command but does something totally different.

Comment: @Refilon I know, but myself I did the same error while helping a junior, i meant fresh but told him to do refresh. His answer is so precise, it must be a typo. nothing a quick edit wont fix.

Comment: @N69S Well I will give him the benefit of the doubt then and retracted my downvote.